# NodeJs : Setting maxRows property in ora-pool

Tags: node.js, oracle

I am using [ora-pool package] (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ora-pool) as a connection pooling mechanism for Oracle DB in my node js application. This internally used oracledb.

Currently its fetching only 100 rows by default (oracledb defaule behavior). I need to change this and override this property.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your query returns a fixed number of rows, or very small number of rows, then use a [ResultSet](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#resultsethandling) or [Stream](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#streamingresults) to get rows from node-oracledb.  With the basic `maxRows`-limited query path you will never know if all possible results are returned (or whether it was truncated to the `maxRows` limit), and you can start to consume memory if `maxRows` is big.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Is there any way to user Resultset or Stream in ora-pool ? Or do I need to stop using ora-pool and switch to node-oracledb ?

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason to use ora-pool, I would recommend you use the base driver: node-oracledb.

Comment: Yes to what Dan said. Enhancements will continue so make sure to report issues and requests to help prioritization.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, 100 rows is the default, but it can be overridden by setting maxRows via the optional Options object passed to execute: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#propdbmaxrows